# Removing white-spaces conditioned on number of occurrences in R

Tags: r, regex, whitespace, gsub

I want to remove white-spaces from a character string when the number of continuous white-spaces between *2 non-whitespace chars* <s>words</s> is less than a certain number.

For example,

```
a <- c("I want            only                <5                         white-spaces   removed")
```

I know I can remove all the spaces using `gsub(' ', '', a)`. However, I want to remove white-spaces between *two non-whitespace chars* <s>words</s> only when the total white-space is less than 5. So I want the following

```
a_adj <- c("Iwant             only                <5                         white-spacesremoved")
```

I tried this `gsub('{,5} ', '', a)`. But it still removes all white-spaces. Can someone help, please?

Thanks

Comment: If by "words" you mean any non-whitespace chars, then you need `a_adj <- gsub("(?<=\\S)\\s{1,4}(?=\\S)", "", a, perl=TRUE)`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I corrected my question now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
a_adj <- gsub("(?<=\\S)\\s{1,4}(?=\\S)", "", a, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xCegA4/3) and the [R demo](https://ideone.com/Pk2bho).

The `(?<=\S)\s{1,4}(?=\S)` matches 1 to 4 whitespaces only when in between any non-whitespace characters.

**Details**

- `(?<=\S)` - a positive lookbehind that requires a non-whitespace character immediately to the left of the current location
- `\s{1,4}` - 1 to 4 whitespace characters
- `(?=\S)` - a positive lookahead that requires a non-whitespace character immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: The second one is what I exactly wanted. Also, thanks for the links to the detailed explanation.

Comment: I used the `\b` version because you mentioned *white-spaces between 2 **words***. A *word* is an ambiguous notion in regex world, you know.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I corrected my question now.

Comment: @MaMu Ok, then I also precised the answer.

Comment: Sorry for asking another question. But I think it complements what's already asked. How can I modify this function to get each individual elements from `a_adj` in a character vector instead of one long string? To be precise, I want this 
`c("Iwant", "only", "<5", "white-spacesremoved")`

Comment: @MaMu `strsplit(gsub("(?<=\\S)\\s{1,4}(?=\\S)", "", a, perl=TRUE), "\\s+")`, see [R demo](https://ideone.com/tNbQlj).

Comment: Great! I managed to do with `a_adj   %>% strsplit(" ") %>%
    sapply(function(x){x[!x ==""]})`. But your solution aovids the use of additional `apply` function. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Using `str_remove_all`

```
library(stringr)
str_remove_all(a, "\\s{1,4}(?! )")
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing another function. I accepted the answer from Wictor for its completeness.